# Compute liminf, limsup

Tags: real-analysis, limsup-and-liminf

I want to compute liminf and limsup of $\left( (-1)^{n^3} \left( 1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^n\right)$.

I have thought the following so far:

From definition we have that $\lim \inf x_n=\lim_{n \to \infty} \left( inf_{k \geq n} x_k \right)$ and $\lim \sup x_n=\lim_{n \to \infty} \left( \sup_{k \geq n} x_k \right)$.

If $k$ is odd, then $(-1)^{k^3} \left( 1+\frac{1}{k}\right)^k=-\left( 1+\frac{1}{k}\right)^k$.

If $k$ is even , then $(-1)^{k^3} \left( 1+\frac{1}{k}\right)^k=\left( 1+\frac{1}{k}\right)^k$.

It holds that $-\left( 1+\frac{1}{k}\right)^k \geq - \left( 1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^k$ and $\left( 1+\frac{1}{k}\right)^k \leq \left( 1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^k$.

But we cannot bound $\left( 1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^k$ and $- \left( 1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^k$ by an expression of $n$, can we? (Thinking)

If not, how can we compute liminf and limsup?

Comment: Whenever you see an expression of the form $(1+{x \over n})^n$ you should be thinking $e^x$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have that

$$\left| (-1)^{n^3} \left( 1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^n\right|\le e$$

and

- $n^3$ even $\implies (-1)^{n^3}\left( 1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^n \to e$
- $n^3$ odd $\implies (-1)^{n^3}\left( 1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^n \to -e$

then we can conclude that $\limsup=e$ and $\liminf=-e$.

Comment: Simple and on point as always ! +1

Comment: @Rebellos Thanks, much appreciative! Bye

Comment: Why does it hold that $\left| (-1)^{n^3} \left( 1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^n\right| \leq e$ ?

Comment: @Evinda If we can show that $|a_n| \le L$ and we find a subsequence such that $a_{n_k} \to L$ therefore $\limsup a_n=L$. And similarly for $\liminf$. It is  a theorem.

Comment: @Evinda We have that $$\left| (-1)^{n^3} \left( 1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^n\right| =\left( 1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^n\leq e$$

Comment: Ah I see... Thanks a lot!!!

Comment: @Evinda Well done! You are welcome! Bye